# Magento Sample Data/Host gator

Tags: magento-1.8, sample-data

I created a website through hostgator, but I am having problems using the magento sample data to the hostgator website. It would be a nice sample template to get me through everything and the rest I could customize.

If you could help me that would be really nice and I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far and what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation from Magento.
Demo data in 1.9 and up works different than prior to 1.9

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-sample-data-archive-for-magento-ce

> Magento CE sample data must be installed before you install Magento CE.

Comment: I've used followed this guide before and it works perfectly.